# Ubuntu 18.4 How to update only security update

Tags: apt, 18.04, security, patch

I use several  Ubuntu 18.4 and I would like to install only security update from command line. What command should I use?,and if it can be automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get your system up-to-date automatically by using unattended-upgrades.
Just:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

Then, you can configure unattended-upgrades to just install security updates and how often it should run. For more information please check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!